# How can i get Partition Serial/ID/Signature?

Tags: c#, wmi, disk, partition, serial-number

I want to know the identifier for a partition when checking the disk.
It's needed for logging, for instance:
If on my computer drive C: is 041d when i plug it to a different computer it will get a different driveletter(D:) but the partition is the same 041d.

How can i get it?

P.S - Not talking about the VolumeSerialNumber that is for the Disk itself, but i'm referring to PartitionSerialNumber(if there is such a thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved using the Index property of the partition.
**Partition Index number is permanent. Win32_DiskPartition**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any property for 'serial' as you want from docu of [Win32_DiskPartitionn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). The most closest definition is DeviceId but maybe it's also not exactly what you want. 
Use [WMI Code Creator](http://hintdesk.com/introduction-to-wmi-code-creator/) to read out the values of the properties on the fly and choose which is the best for you.